# iOS 10.0 UIRefreshControl not showing indicator

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios10, uirefreshcontrol, ios9.3.2

I am using a UITableView Which has a Pull down to refresh function but the spinner for pull down to refresh is not showing up when I call the [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing]

The above code is called inside the viewDidLoad cause the table is loading some data initially. The spinner works fine if I perform a pull down to refresh after the initial refresh. The title shows up but not the spinner.

Cant seem to solve this problem. It works fine on iOS 9.3.2 but not on iOS 10.

Here is the code I am using currently.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupView];
    [self customSetup];
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Updating Discounts..."];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadDeals) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Hi. How are you? Did you find the solution? Thanks you. Greetings.

Comment: enable UITableView bounces  property

Answer (score 23, accepted):

before the code：

`[refreshControl beginRefresh]`

insert the code：

`[refreshControl layoutIfNeeded]`

Comment: This has solved the issue for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This didn't work on iOS 11 for me. Neither did any of the other answers :(

Comment: I ended up delaying the `beginRefreshing()` call and setting the content offset with 0.01s inside `viewWillAppear`. Still getting a few glitches but it's "okay"... @vivektakrani

Answer (score 4):

Delaying call to refresh in viewDidLoad worked for me:

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as @jpros answer but in swift

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
refreshControl.layoutIfNeeded()
refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and reported bug in iOS 10.

[**Radar rdar://27468436**](https://openradar.appspot.com/27468436)

I'm not sure if there are any workarounds.

Comment: seeing as they didn't fix it in GM, is it possible, there's a change and something we need to do differently?

Comment: 10.1 beta out, anyone check yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` to fix it in iOS 10. For my case it was enough to put the call to `viewDidLoad` (I was using storyboard in that project). For other cases `viewWillAppear` fits better.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
   ...
```

Comment: When downvoting please explain why. Otherwise it is pointless

Comment: This works for me after initializing my tableView. For example, calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` on `viewWillAppear`. I'm using swift.

Comment: this worked for me! thank you!! i did have to put it in viewwillappear, not viewdidload.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to fix this by calling, from viewDidLoad():

```
refreshControl.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS10, we should add the UIRefreshControl using setRefreshControl of UITableView or UICollectionView.

```
if([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setRefreshControl:)]) {
    [self.tableView setRefreshControl:self.refreshControl];
}
else {
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
}
[self.refreshControl layoutIfNeeded];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your refresh indicator is not showing try enabling Bounce Vertically in Interface Builder for table view or scroll view.