# UIRefresh for UITableView do not work iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to use UIRefresh to reload UITableView with latest data.

```
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(myRefresh)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];

- (void)myRefresh
{
  //Empty array which hold old data.
 //calling API to get fresh data 
}

-(void)delegatefromAPI
{ 
    //array will be reloaded with data from DB
    [self.tableView reloadtable];
    // End the refreshing
    if (self.refreshControl) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}
```

but the problem is before API call goes to fetch data, cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called (automatically) at this point Array to load each cell empty is empty.
however I'm calling `[self.tableView reloadtable];` after getting data and then calling `"[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]"`. 
but cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called before `[self.tableView reloadtable]` in delegatefromAPI.
where I'm going wrong.....

Comment: Please look into this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39835854/4611751

Comment: check my answer you got your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
 self.refreshControl.tintColor = YOURCOLOR_FOR_REFRESHCONTROL;
 [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(fetchContactList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       self.YOURTABLE.refreshControl = refreshControl
 } else {
       [self.YOURTABLE addSubview:self.refreshControl];
 }



-(void)fetchContactList{
       // your API call inside that stop animation
       [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
       [self.YOURTABLE reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UITableview delegate method
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return YOURARRAY.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"YOURCELLIDENTIFIER";
    RegisteredContactTVCell *cell = (RegisteredContactTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   cell.lblName.text = @"VALUE";
   return cell;
}
```

Output :

[image: CHECK]

Comment: kiran check my answer and instruction